# How to replace mediawiki in url as my wiki name

Tags: mediawiki, bitnami

I am using mediawiki. My url is

http://localhost:1028/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

I need to replace mediawiki in the url say samswiki. So the url should be like

http://localhost:1028/samswiki/index.php/Main_Page

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks

Things that I have tried.

1.) Renamed the folder mediawiki to samswiki.
2.) Changed $wgScriptPath to samswiki in LocalSettings.php
But both did not work

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `installdir/apps/mediawiki/conf/httpd-prefix` and change the alias from `mediawiki` to `samswiki`. Then restart apache and it should work.

Comment: I did as you instructed. But I get this error                                                Not Found

The requested URL /mediawiki/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Is the `/samswiki/` URL working though? Or do you mean you get that error when you go to `/samswiki/`? Anyway, you may also want to add a redirect from `/mediawiki` to `/samswiki`, and while you're at it set up short URLs (i.e. get rid of the `index.php/`) See: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL

Comment: @Sam Wilson. I went through the Manual but Its not much helpful for me since am a beginner. Can you explain me clearly. My requirement is to make this url http://localhost:1028/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page into http://localhost:1028/samswiki